# Azure Service Bus message inspector

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus

Is there any way to intercept Azure service bus messages in a generic way on both sides (sending and receiving)? I would like to generically add properties to messages as they are sent, and read properties as they are received, without having to change the sending or receiving code.

I have found some references to WCF interfaces `IClientMessageInspector` and `IDispatchMessageInspector` in the context of service bus, but I have yet to find a real working sample that connects all the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new [.NET Standard client for Azure Service Bus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/), there are incoming and outgoing pipelines intended exactly for that purpose. You can have a look at some of the already available plugins to get an idea how it works.

- [Message ID plugin](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet-plugins/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageIdPlugin/readme.md)
- [ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin](https://github.com/SeanFeldman/ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin/)

Comment: Looks nice! So, I'm on the old client library. Are there any direct gotchas I need to be aware of if I replace the client library?

Comment: Some.  No management operations yet. Backwards compatibility is not as smooth as it should be. APIs have shifted a bit